# Getting a cell value by using buttons in ASP.NET Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, button, gridview

I have a gridview that has rows with an **asp:Button** and some boundfields as ID, Date, Subject, Username etc. I need to get **ID** value of an item by using **Show** button in that row.
How can I do it in codebehind?

**My ASPX codes:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="BtnGetId" runat="server" Text="Show" OnClick="BtnGetId_Click" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**And my C# codes should be like this:**

```
protected void BtnGetId_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // GETS ROW'S ID VALUE
}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Why not use `RowCommand Event` ?

Comment: @sametenekeci Then you should read about `events` in GridView, Follow these links they will help you , for more links i will add up in answer as it will become messy here in comments. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @sametenekeci Go through this tutorial also http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/syedshakeer/rowcommand-event-in-gridview/

Comment: @SurajSingh Thanks a lot! I got it through this tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use:

```
ForEach(GridViewRow  row In GrdJobDetails.Rows)
{
  variable=(control)(row.findcontrol("controlID"),control).Property
}
```

Above thing i have written syntactically. You will have to mold it according to your case.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="BtnGetId" runat="server" Text="Show" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID")%>' CommandName="btnClick" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

---

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "btnClick")
    {
       int ID = Convert.toInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    }
}
```